# Do we need a "music" tag?

Tags: discussion

Is there a reason we have a [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tag? The site is about music so isn't it kind of implied that questions will be about music in some way, shape, or form. It is tagged in only 4 questions and it seems that it is not really necessary.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can't think of a good reason. Two of those four questions were closed anyhow, and the other two didn't use them to mean something other than the name of the site.

I removed the tags from the questions -- the tag will be removed from the site overnight.