# Burn the [music] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[We've already discussed how the music tag does not have a use on this site in this question](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/698/do-we-need-a-music-tag), can we please burn the [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tag? It has started cropping up again.

Comment: OTOH,  that tag is disallowed for questions related to Celine Dion.

Comment: Is this blacklisted yet?

Comment: I don't think it is, as I was able to add [music] to one of my own questions. (I removed it, by the way.)

Answer (score 18):

The [music](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) tag should be blacklisted as [intrinsic tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/218532).

> If your site has a term that can apply to *all* questions on the site and folks are persistent about trying to use it as a tag, post a request on your meta and we'll mark it as intrinsic.

Answer (score 11):

I mean, I'm hardly qualified to render my opinion, but I'm pretty confident that all the questions here are in some way related to music (if they weren't, they'd be off-topic).

**No, I don't see any reason to have that tag** - I support any motion to blacklist [music], and I think very few here would disagree with us.